# Bind EventHandler for custom form controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, reflection

I am trying to bind an event to a form element created in a custom Form class. I am quite clueless as to how I can bind the method that exists on the class FormLoader, a UserControl file.
Ex:

```
 public class FormBuilder 
{
public Control Create(){
//create form controls here... for each control call AddEvent.
}
void AddEvent(object o, string eventname, string methodname)
    {
        EventInfo ei = o.GetType().GetEvent(eventname);
        MethodInfo mi = typeof (FormLoader).GetMethod(methodname, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Default);
        Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, typeof (FormLoader), mi);
        ei.AddEventHandler(o, del);
    }}
```

This is how I instantiate my form.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Form = new Form();
        Controls.Add(Form.Create());

    }

    public void ProcessEventAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"Control Internal Hit");
    }
```

I am getting "Error binding to target method." Any idea how I can bind method for the event that exists outside scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overload of [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) which takes `Type, Type, MethodInfo` as its arguments. As a result, you're calling the [`Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type, Object, MethodInfo)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx), passing `typeof(FormLoader)` as the first argument.

Since the `MethodInfo` you're passing in is not defined on the `Type` class, it can't be bound to a `Type` instance.

You need to pass an instance of your `FormLoader` class as the second parameter of the `CreateDelegate` method. Assuming you don't want to use a new instance for each event, you'll need to pass the instance in to the `AddEvent` method.

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately I still get "Error binding to target method".

Comment: @xoail: Sorry, didn't notice that the handler isn't on the `o` object. You'll need an instance of `FormLoader` to build the delegate.